# android, how to programatically capture which On screen keypad key is pressed during call?

Tags: android, dtmf

How to capture the key presses during a call. They way user navigates IVRs when they call an operator they press 1 or some other key to select language and so on. Is there a way to programtically capture these key presses?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

On the client side?  No.  There's no API for that.  On the other side they obviously can.  The only thing I could think of would be in you could record from the mic and do signal analysis looking for a dtmf tone, but my dialer has an option not to make beep noises when keys are pressed.

Comment: they how IVRs do it without mic?

Comment: @user924 Those happen in the other end- on the computer that receives the call. Not on the client's phone

Comment: I understand this, how do they get such events? for example if I have two android devices, during a call can I detect numbers on some device user pressed on the other device ?

Comment: They listen to the tone. This is 1980s tech